# R combine data frames and create grouping variable dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the easiest dplyr way to merge two data frames with identical variables while creating an identifier variable with group labels for the different observations.

```
dfA <- c('y','x','z')
dfB  <- c(345, 443, 123)

a <- data.frame(dfA,dfB)
b <- data.frame(dfA,dfB)

#What I want:

  dfA dfB group
1   y 345 a
2   y 345 b
3   x 443 a
4   x 443 b
5   z 123 a
6   z 123 b
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work.

Comment: .. specifically, you reference objects `x` and `y` in your assignments to `a` and `b` and these objects don't exist.

Comment: soz, wrong names there.

Answer (score 1):

This may also serve the purpose

```
a$Group <- "a"
b$Group <- "b"
rbind(a, b)

> rbind(a, b)
  dfA dfB Group
1   y 345     a
2   x 443     a
3   z 123     a
4   y 345     b
5   x 443     b
6   z 123     b
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve; maybe this helps?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

  data.frame(dfA, dfB, group_a = "a", group_b = "b") %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("group"), values_to  = "group") %>% 
  select(-name)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   dfA     dfB group
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 y       345 a    
#> 2 y       345 b    
#> 3 x       443 a    
#> 4 x       443 b    
#> 5 z       123 a    
#> 6 z       123 b
```

**data**

```
dfA <- c('y','x','z')
dfB  <- c(345, 443, 123)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>